# Load data asynchronously to view in .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-2.2

I am consuming wego api to list out the flight. but i will get small amount of data in each request so i want to load all data asynchronously to the view .Is there any solution in .net core

For data pulling I am using the below code. so after reach to view i don't want to stop the data getting.because I got only 100 records i need to get the remaining data in view and here there is no pagination

```
const int numberOfResultsToGet = 100;
var results = new List<SearchResultMv>();
while (results.Count < numberOfResultsToGet)
{
    var response = await GetFlights(flightParam, auth);
    results.AddRange(response.Results);

    // update offset
    flightParam.Offset += response.Results.Count;

    // sleep for 1 second before sending another request
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: The problem in reading a request in pieces you do not get the closing tag(s) until the entire request is consumed.  That is why a lot of sites use streaming data in xml format so partial data can be read.  In your case it looks like you get a complete request so I do not understand what is the advantage of asynchronous processing.

Comment: I have edited my query

Comment: When you say you are loading data in the view.... do you mean you are calling an api from your controller? Is this and MVC application? Is this BLAZOR?  What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: I am using .net core 2.2 mvc. I want to data loading asynchronously from my controle to view apart from ajax call is there any way ?

Comment: You understand everything right: you need to make an ajax request using javascript from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int Parallelism => 5;
    int NumberOfResultsToGet = 100;
           [HttpGet("get")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFlightsAsync()
    {
        var flights = await 
        GetFlightsByPartitionAsync(GetPages(NumberOfResultsToGet));
        return Ok(flights);
    }

    private async Task<List<SearchResult>> GetFlightsByPartitionAsync(IList<int> 
   pages)
    {
        var result = new List<SearchResult>();

        var output = System.Collections.Concurrent.Partitioner
               .Create(pages)
               .GetPartitions(Parallelism)
               .Select(partition => Task.Run(async () =>
               {
                   using (partition)
                   {
                       while (partition.MoveNext())
                       {
                 // Perform your logic here
                           lock (result)
                               result.Add(new SearchResult() { FlightNo = partition.Current });
                       }
                   }
               }));

        await Task.WhenAll(output);
        return result;
    }
    private IList<int> GetPages(int results)
    {
        IList<int> pages = new List<int>();
        for (int iteration = 1; iteration <= results; iteration++)
            pages.Add(iteration);

        return pages;
    }
```